# What's the accurate potential energy for an angular system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, potential-energy

> [image]
> In the above figure, at 'F' point there's a massive Iron (whose mass is $m$) attached with a string whose mass is negligible. And 3 m below from the point F there's a silver ball. The height of the table is 2 m. The depth of that table is 0 and that table is frictionless. Distance from the ball (on table) and edge of that table is 40 cm. Pendulum's string length is 3 m. At some moment, if we release the ball (which is attached with string) at 70 degree angle than it will hit the ball which is on top of that table. Let, radius of both ball is 0 m. After hitting the ball (which was on table) it will cross the table and fall some distance away. Now find the distance.

I saw someone writing that Potential energy is $m_0gl(1-\cos\phi)$

From the conservation law he wrote that
$$m_0gl(1-\cos\phi)=\frac{1}{2}mv_{max}^2$$
And solved the problem following way,
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$$
So, $$d=v_{max}t=\sqrt{2gl(1-\cos\phi)}\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$$ then he just put numeric values. What I am assuming that is his Potential energy is wrong. In my general sense, that should be $mgh\cos\phi$ I had solved it by integration either.

$$E=\int F\cdot ds$$
$$=\int m\ddot{x}\cos\phi ds$$
$$\text{P.E}=m\ddot{x}s\cos\phi$$
$$E=\int F\cdot ds$$
$$=\int \frac{dp}{dt}\cdot ds$$
$$=\int dp\cdot v$$
$$=\int v m\mathrm dv$$
$$\text{K.E}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

So conservation law says
$$mgh\cos\phi=\frac{1}{2}mv_{max}^2$$ Then I can move on. My question is, "Did he take accurate Potential energy or am I?"

I think it's not a homework-and-exercises question. It's rather about direction.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kinetic energy equal potential energy

your equation

$$\frac m2\,v^2=m\,g\,l\,(1-\cos(\theta))$$

for t=0 $~\theta=\pi/2~$ hence $~v^2=m\,g\,l$ but the velocity v must be zero at t=0, so your PE is wrong !

Answer (score 0):

In the picture $\theta=0$ is at the bottom. That means that the potential function has a minimum at $\theta=0$. The $\cos$ function has a maximum at $\theta=0$ so it must be flipped with a negative sign. So your friend is correct